# Savon 2 client returning blank array for response in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I am using **savon** gem for integrating **paysbuy** in my project which is made in Ruby on Rails. This is how I am creating the savon client

```
client = Savon.client do
endpoint "https://www.paysbuy.com/receiveresponse/Result.aspx"
namespace "https://www.paysbuy.com/receiveresponse/ResultReg.aspx"
wsdl "https://demo.paysbuy.com/api_paynow/api_paynow.asmx"
end  
logger.info"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#{client.operations}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5555555"
```

But the response for "**client.operations**" is coming as "**[]**". I need help for rectifying anything wrong doing in my side. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't know anything about paysbuy specifically, but you need to pass a WSDL file to the `wsdl:` option. By browsing to the URL that you've used, I can see immediately that this isn't a WSDL.

Comment: Ok, then can you tell me how can I pass the URL in the Savon client ?

Comment: Well, find out where the WSDL is located, and replace `https://demo.paysbuy.com/api_paynow/api_paynow.asmx` with that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Savon 2.x?
The syntax of your call is not correct. You need a parameter list not a block.

You also mix WSDL with WSDL less calling convention. You either specify

```
wsdl:
```

or

```
endpoint: ...
namespace: ...
```

`client.operations` doesn't work because you didn't give it a correct wsdl url.

Giving that's a MS based interface it is safe to assume that you can retrieve the WSDL with the parameter `?WSDL` at the URL. Try this:

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "https://demo.paysbuy.com/api_paynow/api_paynow.asmx?wsdl",
    log: true,
    log_level: debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
)

print client.operations
```

Unfortunately that call fails using Savon. I suspect it can't interpret the WSDL document.

What you can do is to use SoapUI to inspect your service and build a client without a WSDL.

```
client = Savon.client(
    endpoint: "https://demo.paysbuy.com/api_paynow/api_paynow.asmx",
    namespace: "http://tempuri.org",
    log: true,
    log_level: debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
)
```

I read the WSDL and found something which might be the namespace, but that can be tricky. Sometimes it needs some tinkering to find the correct request.
When you've found a working request using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), you need to translate it into Ruby code to make it work. That was always my approach at least.
Feel free to ask when you've reached that point.